# how to direct a link to a page and then add class to the body of that page after it is loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a template which has `blog.html` file with several different layouts:

- full-width layout
- 2 column layout
- 3 column layout
- 4 column layout

I have styled the blog.html so that when I add a specific classes to the body tag, each layout is displayed. so, when the user click on the link of each layout in nav menu, the classes are added to the body tag. the jquery code is this:

```
$('.nav .full-width').click(function (e) {
    $('body').addClass('blog-full-width');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works well *ONLY* when I'm on the blog page itself. but I connot do this from other pages.
I mean, how do I use jquery so that when I click the link 'Full-width Blog' in nav menu on index page, the link go to the blog page and then add the class 'blog-full-width' to the body tag of the blog.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Put the class in a query string on the URL, have the page look for it and apply it.
2. Store the class in session storage (or local storage if you want it to persist) and have the page look for it and apply it. Web storage [has very good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).
3. Store it in a cookie (avoid if possible!) and have the page look for it and apply it.

You will have noted the common feature all of those had: Code on the *target* page must make the change, you can't have a link that replaces the current window when clicked and then runs some JavaScript code on the new page in the window. (You could if you were opening new windows, but I assume you aren't.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make an indication someware, like an anchor for example and in the new page you look for the anchor, if it exists you add the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  if(hash =="indication")
    $("body").addClass("class_to_add");
});
```

if the two pages are in the same domain, you can use the cookies as indication. you use a library like [this one](https://github.com/khaliid/happy-cookies.js) for example to add a cookie and to get the cookie in the other page

```
// in first page
 $.setCookie("indication","value"); 

// in second page
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.getCookie("indication") =="value")
    $("body").addClass("class_to_add");
});
```